# Writing to XML failing abruptly

Tags: libxml2

We have C on windows program in which we are writing some data we call as test results to an xml file.
We use libxml2-2.9.4 API to parse and write to XML.

Each test is described by its test tag "test_info" and the test result with tag "result".
We write each test along with its result as follows:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
        <?xml-stylesheet href="style/results.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
        <all_test_result>
              <test_info TestNumber="1" TestName="test1" Duration="90s" TestServer="s1">
                <result FaultCount="0" TestRunTime="0.00" testResult="success"/>
              ....
              <test_info TestNumber="13" TestName="test14" Duration="90s" TestServer="s1">
                <result FaultCount="0" TestRunTime="0.00" testResult="success"/>
             <test_info TestNumber="14" TestName="test15" Duration="90s" TestServer="s1">
                <result FaultCount="0" TestRunTime="0.00" testResult="success"/>
             <test_info TestNumber="15" TestName="test16" Duration="90s" TestServer="s1">
                <result FaultCount="0" TestRunTime="0.00" testResult="success"/>
         </all_test_result>
```

We use function "xmlSaveFormatFileEnc" to write to XML.
Code snippet:

```
  xmlDocPtr outDoc        = NULL;
  xmlNodePtr np           = NULL;
  xmlNodePtr rootnode     = NULL;
  xmlNodePtr testinfonode     = NULL;
  LIBXML_TEST_VERSION
  resXml = xmlNewDoc(BAD_CAST "1.0");
    if (resXml != NULL)
  {
    rootnode = xmlNewDocNode(resXml, NULL, BAD_CAST "all_test_result", NULL);
    xmlDocSetRootElement(resXml, rootnode);

    testinfonode = xmlNewChild(rootnode, NULL, BAD_CAST "test_info", NULL);
    ....
    xmlNewProp(testinfonode, BAD_CAST "TestName", testName);
    ...
    np = xmlNewDocPI(resXml, BAD_CAST "xml-stylesheet", BAD_CAST "href=\"style/results.xsl\" type=\"text/xsl\"");
    xmlAddPrevSibling(xmlDocGetRootElement(resXml), np);
    xmlSaveFormatFileEnc(resultXmlFile, resXml, MY_ENCODING, 1);
    ...
```

The test xml file is written every 1 second and some 0 to 200 tests tags along with their result tags are written each time in the file.
Many times the result xml file is written properly and completely.

Some times the file is not written completely and stops abrubptly like it will write incomplete file:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
        <?xml-stylesheet href="style/results.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
        <all_test_result>
              <test_info TestNumber="1" TestName="test1" Duration="90s" TestServer="s1">
                <result FaultCount="0" TestRunTime="0.00" testResult="success"/>
              <test_info TestNumber="13" TestName="test14" Duration="90s" TestServer="s1">
                <result FaultCount="0" TestRunTime="0.00" testResult="success"/>
             <test_info TestNumber="14" TestName="test15" Duration="90s" TestServer="s1">
                <result FaultCount="0" TestRunTime="0.00"
```

And then we get the error:

```
error : string is not in UTF-8
error : string is not in UTF-8
error : string is not in UTF-8
error : string is not in UTF-8
error : string is not in UTF-8
error : string is not in UTF-8
I/O error : encoder error
```

Any suggestion why is this happening and how to resolve this error?

Comment: Maybe you add invalid UTF-8 to the document like random non-ASCII bytes?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will check. The XML tags are written in the file using for loop. I have notes that if I add some printfs in the for loop then all test tags gets written. Without printfs the issue crops up. May be printfs is adding some delay which helps the libxml API to finish the printing. But adding print delay is not a good solution. Moroover I cannot add delay like this. Need to check for some other solution.